# Hindi Characters in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file that has newline characters in some of its column values. So, when I load this data in Hive via Spark SQL, I end up using `saveAsTable()` to create the table instead of the direct create table command since `saveAsTable()` creates a table link in Hive while also storing newline characters (which is not possible with the usual inserts).

But then in the same file/table, I have some hindi language values (stored in unicode characters (`\u****`). Now I need these values to be displayed in the table or at least I need to prepare a `select` query that can extract the records from this table such that the hindi language values are displayed.

I understand that `tblproperties` can be used to set the `characterset` in the table to store hindi values. 
But since I am creating my table using `saveAsTable` and not the usual create table command, I tried to run -

```
alter table node set TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='windows-1252')
```

after the table was created with just one dummy record.

But looks like this didn't work.

Is there a way for me to store or at least extract the correctly displayed values in hindi?

Comment: Could you try to encode unicode characters to ascii during inserts or while calling saveAsTable() and decode it when you fetch it?

Comment: I tried to read the file as hiveContext.read.option("encoding", "utf-8").json("file.json"). But even then hindi characters are not displayed.